# Pivot Query - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have the following query in SQL Server 2005 that fetches the result that is mentioned below it.

```
select Distinct(date),id,
           sum(convert(float,Gross)),
           count(*) as no from Daily
    group by date,id 
    order by date desc

Date                     id          Gross          Count
2012-11-25 00:00:00.000  Client id1  1232.6140752   12
2012-11-25 00:00:00.000  Client id2  1183.75621528  88
2012-11-26 00:00:00.000  Client id3  4561.459086    67
2012-11-26 00:00:00.000  Client id4  6781.15660608  440
```

Now how do I get the result in the following format. This looks like a pivot query is reqd please help

```
id           Date1  Date2  Date3  Date4  Date5 Date6 Date7
Client id1   Gross       
Client id2   Gross
Client id3   Gross
```

Comment: Do you want the column to says `Date1`, `Date2` or should the column have the date value?

Comment: The date value...all days in a month will be present in the table...so for every day we have gross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways that you can `PIVOT`, either a static version where you hard-code all of the date values or a dynamic version which will generate the list of dates at run-time.

*Static Version:*

If you had a limited number of dates your query will be similar to this.

```
select id, [yourDate1], [yourDate2], [yourDate3]
from
(
  select date, id, cast(gross as float) as gross
  from Daily
) src
pivot
(
  sum(gross)
  for date in ([yourDate1], [yourDate2], [yourDate3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5cd9/2)

*Dynamic Version:*

This version generates dynamic SQL to get the list of dates at run-time. Your code will be similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(date) 
                    from Daily
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
               select date, id, cast(gross as float) as gross
               from Daily
            ) src
            pivot 
            (
                sum(gross)
                for date in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b836/1)

Comment: Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.
When the Dynamic query is used.

Comment: @Moonwalk if your `gross` field is a `varchar` then you need to perform the `convert` in the inner query.  See my edit

Comment: Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
No column was specified for column 3 of 'src'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'gross'.

Comment: @Moonwalk did you place an alias on the `convert` of `gross`?  It has to have an alias on the column.

Comment: Yes...the cast function has been used . Need only the dynamic query.

Comment: @Moonwalk it should be working, see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b836/1 -- Can you create a SQL Fiddle demo with the query you are using?

Comment: @Moonwalk It doesn't matter if that is a varchar it is not being used in the aggregate function

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'Gross'.

Comment: @Moonwalk what is the table structure?  Can you create a sql fiddle with your table, sample data and the query you are using?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[\Daily](
 [date] [datetime] NULL,
 [id] [varchar](100) NULL,
 [Gross] [varchar](100) NULL
)  - 2012-11-25 00:00:00.000                   abc-2e 2944.816429
2012-11-25 00:00:00.000     cde4-e -0.0009632
2012-11-25 00:00:00.000      aupyt 12.1852368
2012-11-25 00:00:00.000      fus92 728.91516392
2012-11-25 00:00:00.000         uk 87.5783408  - USING SQL SERVER 2005

Comment: SQL Server 2005 is in use - is that the cause?

Comment: @Moonwalk no, SQL Server 2005 has the `PIVOT` function

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH a AS
(
    SELECT [Id], [Gross]
    , [DateRank] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Date])
    FROM [Daily]
)
SELECT *
FROM a PIVOT
(
    SUM([Gross])
    FOR [DateRank] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
) b
```